# How to output loop.index in jinja

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I want to be able to output the loop.index iteration to my template , i am using ansible and i have template file.j2 and inventory file have the below group

```
[all_servers]
app01 ansible_host=10.10.1.100
app02 ansible_host=10.10.1.102
app03 ansible_host=10.10.1.103
app04 ansible_host=10.10.1.104
app05 ansible_host=10.10.1.105
app06 ansible_host=10.10.1.106
```

I have jinja file inside this file value

`/kafka_certification/kafka.server01.keystore.jk`

> So i want copy this jinja file to all nodes and i want use loop.index
> in part of [ **server0{{ loop.index }}** ] because each node have
> different jinja file for example  kafka.server**02**.keystore for
> app02 kafka.server**03**.keystore for app03
> kafka.server**04**.keystore for app04 kafka.server**05**.keystore for
> app05 kafka.server**06**.keystore for app06 .. loop depend on my
> inventory host group [all_servers]

how i can do this

ansible loop index for ansible template

Comment: no i want to user {{loop.index}} but i dont know how it this case

Comment: i want to change 01 only to be 02 03 04 05 05 depend on host group all_servers

Comment: I modified again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play below shows how you can use the index

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ file }} to {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        index: "{{ '%02d' % ansible_loop.index }}"
        file: "/kafka_certification/kafka.server{{ index }}.keystore.jk"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server01.keystore.jk to app01
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server02.keystore.jk to app02
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server03.keystore.jk to app03
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server04.keystore.jk to app04
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server05.keystore.jk to app05
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server06.keystore.jk to app06
```

---

There is a simpler approach. The play below gives the same result without iteration

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ file }} to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      vars:
        idx: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
        index: "{{ '%02d' % idx|int }}"
        file: "/kafka_certification/kafka.server{{ index }}.keystore.jk"
```

This option complies with the Ansible context. See [Plays](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/getting_started/basic_concepts.html#plays):

> ... playbook object **maps** managed nodes (hosts) to tasks.

---

Q: ***"Copy file to all nodes. Use loop.index on inventory host group [all_servers]"***

A: In this particular case the play below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: all_servers

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ file }} to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      vars:
        idx: "{{ groups.all_servers.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
        index: "{{ '%02d' % idx|int }}"
        file: "/kafka_certification/kafka.server{{ index }}.keystore.jk"
```

```yaml
PLAY [all_servers] ****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [app02] => 
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server02.keystore.jk to app02
ok: [app01] => 
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server01.keystore.jk to app01
ok: [app04] => 
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server04.keystore.jk to app04
ok: [app03] => 
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server03.keystore.jk to app03
ok: [app05] => 
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server05.keystore.jk to app05
ok: [app06] => 
  msg: Copy /kafka_certification/kafka.server06.keystore.jk to app06

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
app01: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
app02: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
app03: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
app04: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
app05: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
app06: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```